# Как сделать такую яндекс карту?

Tags: css

Как сделать такую яндекс карту?

Comment: @Руслан Сабанов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот [пример внедрения карты](http://sto-dts.dp.ua/?page_id=9), с построением маршрутов из разных частей города.
Подключаем АПИ Яндекс Карт:

```
< script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard,package.route&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script >
```

и добавляем карту, предварительно нужно определить через тот же Яндекс координаты нужного места и вставить в коде:

```
ymaps.ready(init); 
var myMap, myPlacemark, myRoute;
function init(){
myMap = new ymaps.Map ("contact-map", { center: [48.457643,34.972106], zoom: 15  });                   
myMap.controls.add(new ymaps.control.ZoomControl());
myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([48.457643,34.972106], { hintContent: 'СТО ДТС',      balloonContent: 'ул. Новоорловская, 30'});
myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);  
}

function r1(n){ 
if(myRoute !== undefined) myMap.geoObjects.remove(myRoute);
var arr = [['Днепропетровск, ул.Красная, 3', 'Днепропетровск, ул.Новоорловская, 30'],['Днепропетровск, пр.Мира,1', 'Днепропетровск, ул.Новоорловская, 30'],['Днепропетровск, Тополь-3,1', 'Днепропетровск, ул.Новоорловская, 30']];
ymaps.route( arr[n], { mapStateAutoApply: true  }).then(
    function (route) { myRoute = route; myMap.geoObjects.add(myRoute); },
    function (error) { alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + error.message); }
);
}
```

функция r1(n) вешается на кнопку для продожения соответствующего маршрута, эси маршруты не нужны - то кнопки не делаем и r1() можно выкинуть.

Comment: а куда вставить этот код?

Comment: это не совсем то,мне надо чтобы там была информация об организации

Comment: Ну очевидно же, что любая необходимая информация, в т.ч. и верстка, вставляется в содержимое balloonContent при создании объекта ymaps.Placemark

Answer (score 4):

Это делает через API яндекс карт, вот тут посмотрите - http://api.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/